# Switch MS Edge version from 44.18362.449.0 to 44.17763.831.0

Tags: browser, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have received report with an issue with React component reproduced only on a specific MS Edge version (`44.17763.831.0`).
How can I test it if both laptops have same Edge version (`44.18362.449.0`)?

Where can I download specific Edge build or how can change engine version without downgrading Windows or running VM with specific Windows build?

Or any other ideas on how to test it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't download Edge Legacy alone as it's a part of Windows. Edge Legacy has different versions according to different Windows OS build. If you don't want to downgrading your Windows version, I think you can test it in a VM with certain Edge Legacy version.

I have a VM with Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0 and it's **Windows version is 1809, OS build 17763.1098.** You can refer to it and test in your VM with the same version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Windows build number containing required Edge version!